# Почему не оправляется почта в django?

Tags: django

Пытаюсь отправить почту по умолчании. в djngo.
Получаю вот такой ответ:

```
Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение
```

в консоли (при её использовании):

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Subject:
 =?utf-8?b?0KHQsdGA0L7RgSDQv9Cw0YDQvtC70Y8g0L3QsCAxMjcuMC4wLjE6ODAwMA==?=
From: webmaster@localhost
To: boleev@mail.ru
Date: Fri, 26 Mar 2021 08:24:12 -0000
Message-ID: <161674705288.13744.361586261144119886@Scorpion>


Вы получили это письмо, потому что вы (или кто-то другой) запросили восстановление пароля от учётной записи на сайте 127.0.0.1:8000, которая связана с этим 
адресом электронной почты.

Пожалуйста, перейдите на эту страницу и введите новый пароль:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/reset/MQ/ak47oc-02a566ce6848f8e1b44b92b90a1c40f2/

Ваше имя пользователя (на случай, если вы его забыли): admin

Спасибо, что используете наш сайт!

Команда сайта 127.0.0.1:8000
```

Comment: Изменил почту отправления - ошибки нет, но и письма не доходят до адресата.

Answer (score 1):

Прочитал про настройки на определенном ресурсе. Скорректировал. Все работает. Нужно обязательно, как я понял, указать какой-нибудь сторонний SMTP сервер (поправьте меня, если не так).

для mail.ru

```
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = '.......@mail.ru'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mail.ru'
EMAIL_PORT = 2525
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_USE_SSL = False
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '.......@mail.ru'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '................'
```

Comment: А лучше не сторониий, а установить и настроить свой собственный SMTP-сервер

Comment: Можно пример? Про настройку собственного?